# How do I access a function within a virtual environment package on PyCharm

Tags: python, function, pycharm, virtualenv

I have my virtual environment set up in PyCharm. Typically when I press command-B it takes me to the source function. This is not taking me into my virtual environment packages / that source function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In PyCharm, make sure that your project interpreter is set to the correct path.**

Open `File > Settings > Project: [name] > Project Interpreter`

[image: Screenshot]

Select your `venv` from the dropdown list. If it's not there, add one by clicking `Add Local` on the bottom of the dropdown.

You can either select an existing environment path, or create one from the GUI.

Once your environment is selected, make sure all of the packages you need are listed.

For example, in the above screenshot you can see the global packages I have installed. I have a `virtalenv` for projects that use the `rewrite` branch of a library, because it's incompatible with other versions.

When I select that environment (if it's a public one), I can see all of the packages I have installed for that specific Python instance.

[image: screenshot]

After you select the correct environment, all the packages should show definitions when you `CTRL+Click` or use other shortcuts.

See more on PyCharm's documentation for virtual environments.

**Adding Existing Virtual Environment:** https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html

**Creating a Virtual Environment:** https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Good luck!